# "Preview Transform" gives error message in VS2017

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2017, ide

I recently upgraded to Visual Studio 2017. For my WCF-Web-Service projects I have different config files for different publish settings.

When I click on the "Preview Transform" entry in the context menu I get the error message:

```
The assembly '' containing the transform build task could not be found.
```

However, if I publish the Service, the transformation is applied.

The curious thing is, I have two development PCs. I upgraded to Vs2017 on both and I get this error on BOTH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. This seems to be a Bug in Visual Studio 17 v15.8.1. Upgrading to v15.8.2 resolves this issue:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#15.8.2

> - Preview Transform gives error.
>     https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/310891/preview-transform-gives-error.html

Comment: Had a problem just with nuget update (for MSTest adapter) failure on VS2017 and was a bug so updated to VS15.8 two weeks back downloading 10 gb and installing. And now this one, perhaps to fix this again dl 10 gig

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/update-a-network-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2017 here is a instruction how to update your installation without downloading the whole installer again! ;-)

Comment: If I have to configure every other thing, yeah perhaps should better start working with VSCode rather than VS.. ;)

Comment: I am having this issue with VS2022 (Version 17.1.2).